# Как можно решить данную задачу через методы?

Tags: c#, массивы, методы

Как можно решить данную задачу через методы, чтобы в методе Main было только объявление массива и не более одной Int переменной? Если можно, то самым простым способом.

```
string s; 
int z = 0; 
int max, min; 

Console.WriteLine("Введите элементы массива"); 
s = Console.ReadLine(); 

string[] str = s.Split(' '); 
int[] a = new int[str.Length]; 

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)  
{
    a[i] = Convert.ToInt32(str[i]); 
}

Console.WriteLine("Введите минимальный элемент "); 
min = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 

Console.WriteLine("Введите максимальный элемент "); 
max = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 

Console.WriteLine("Индексы элементов");

for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) 
{
    if ((a[i] > min) && (a[i] < max)) 
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ", i);
         z++; 
     }
}
Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.NewLine}Количество индексов: {z}");
```

Comment: код с таким форматированием даже смотреть не хочется

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c)

Comment: Самое простое и доступное - просто почитать книги по C#

Comment: Меню в Visual Studio: Edit > Advanced > Format Document. Или просто нажмите шорткат Ctrl+E, D.

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание, что для работы данного кода необходимо подключить пространство имен: `using System.Linq;`

Если вы не хотите использовать автоматический поиск Min и Max, а хотите получать их с клавиатуры, то замените соответствующие методы на `int minOrMax = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введите элементы массива");
    string str = Console.ReadLine();

    int[] arr = GetIntArray(str);

    //В метод как аргументы передаю массив и два метода, которые возвращают в своем теле int
    int count = GetIndexCount(arr, GetMin(arr), GetMax(arr));

    Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.NewLine}Количество индексов: {count}");
}

private static int[] GetIntArray(string str)
{
    string[] strArray = str.Split(' ');
    int[] intArray = new int[strArray.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
        intArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(strArray[i]);

    return intArray;
}
private static int GetIndexCount(int[] array, int min, int max)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((array[i] > min) && (array[i] < max))
        {
            count++;
            Console.Write("{0} ", i);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
private static int GetMin(int[] array)
{
    return array.Min();
}
private static int GetMax(int[] array)
{
    return array.Max();
}
```

Comment: неплохо бы подправить отступы у кода. Если из студии вставляли, то выделите код и нажмите несколько раз Shift+Tab, чтобы к левой границе его подтянуть (главное - не переборщить). Потом через Ctrl+Z это можно откатить после того как скопируете код.

Comment: @aepot спасибо, буду знать